# Mediawiki: can not get ConfirmAccount Extension to work

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I installed ConfirmAccount Extension according to the instructions provided here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount

When a new user clicks the 'Request account' link on the top right of the page, it  refreshes and nothing has changes.  It remains on the 'Login required' Page.

```
Product Version
MediaWiki   1.26.0
PHP 5.3.3 (apache2handler)
MySQL   5.6.17
```

There are no entries in the apache error log.

The apache access log simply gives:

```
108.x.x.x - - [03/Dec/2015:17:29:09 -0500] "GET /index.php/Special:RequestAccount HTTP/1.1" 200 9692 "http://wiki.mycompany.com/index.php/Special:RequestAccount" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.2.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.7"
108.x.x.x - - [03/Dec/2015:17:29:10 -0500] "GET /opensearch_desc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 926 "-" "com.apple.Safari.SearchHelper/10601.2.3 CFNetwork/720.5.7 Darwin/14.5.0 (x86_64)"
```

I ran the update.php and the additional database tables where created.

The upload directory is writable.

Here is some of my LocalSettings.php

```
...

$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;

...

require_once "$IP/extensions/ConfirmAccount/ConfirmAccount.php";
$wgConfirmAccountContact = "me@mycompany.com";
```

Does anyone know what I should check next?  Thanks.

Comment: Please read the extension documentation before asking questions. The answer to your problem is described there. Please also read the "Known issues" part, as what's described there is going to be your *next* problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Thank you @Tgr for pointing me in the right direction.

1. Add the following to LocalSettings.php:

   $wgWhitelistRead = array( 'Special:RequestAccount', 'Main Page' );

It is mentioned in the the "Optional Configuration" section of the Doc.

2. Change this to be true:

   $wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = true;

It is listed in the 'Known Issues' section of the Doc.

3. For 1.26 there's a bug that causes this error message:

   Could not create directory "mwstore://accountcreds-backend/accountcreds-public/w/wi/wik"

You need to make an edit on extensions/ConfirmAccount/ConfirmAccount.config.php - add {$IP} to this line so that it reads:

```
$wgFileStore['accountcreds']['directory'] : "{$IP}/images/accountcreds",
```

Thanks to Eburcat here for that fix: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Extension_talk:ConfirmAccount/Could_not_create_directory_%22mwstore://accountcreds-backend/accountcreds-public/w/wi/wik%22.

Go ConfirmAccount Extension!